# Tuple of sequence

Tags: c++

I would like to store a sequence of classes into a tuple and declare this sequence as a member of another class:

```
template<size_t id> class Foo {};

template<size_t N>
class FooContainer
{
  std::tuple<Foo<0>, Foo<1>, ..., Foo<N>> tup; // build this type at compile time ??
};
```

I tried this:

```
template<size_t N>
class FooContainer
{
  template<size_t... id>
  struct FoosImpl {
    constexpr FoosImpl(std::index_sequence<id...>) {};
    using type = std::tuple<Foo<id>...>;
  };

  template<size_t N, typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
  using Foos = decltype(FoosImpl(Indices())::type);

  Foos<N> tup;
};
```

But this doesn't compiles. GCC complains:
`error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token using Foos = decltype(FoosImpl(Indices())::type);`

I thought the compiler wouldn't need the template to be specified and that it would deduce the integer sequence from `Indices()`. But this doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible way of doing what you want:

```
#include <tuple>

template<size_t id> class Foo {};

template <size_t... Idx>
std::tuple<Foo<Idx>...> get_foos(std::index_sequence<Idx...>);

template <size_t N>
using foo_tuple = decltype(get_foos(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));

template<size_t N>
class FooContainer {
     foo_tuple<N> tup;
};
```

You cannot (currently) let the compiler deduce the class template parameters (as you would need with `FoosImpl`), but you can let it deduce the template parameters of a functions and use the return type.

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know the compiler couldn't deduce the template parameters of a class. I'm still running into a problem: when I want to call `std::get<i>(tup)` the compiler doesn't seem to recognize that tup is a std::tuple and thinks it is a `int&` ?

Comment: @user3719401 Looks very strange - is `i` a compile time constant?

Comment: Yes `i` is a compile time constant. I used the solution if W.F. below which explicitly declares `foos` as a `std::tuple`. Then it compiles.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from your example, you can do this:

```
#include<tuple>
#include<utility>
#include<type_traits>

template<size_t id> class Foo {};

template<size_t N>
struct FooContainer
{
  template<size_t... id>
  static constexpr std::tuple<Foo<id>...> func(std::index_sequence<id...>) {}

  using Foos = decltype(func(std::make_index_sequence<N>()));

  Foos foos;
};

int main() {
  static_assert(std::is_same<FooContainer<3>::Foos, std::tuple<Foo<0>, Foo<1>, Foo<2>>>::value, "!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you could simply use additional parameter to your FooContainer with default value of `std::index_sequence<0,...,N>` like:

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<size_t I> class Foo {};

template <size_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct FooContainer;

template <size_t N, size_t... Is>
struct FooContainer<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
   using Foos = std::tuple<Foo<Is>...>;
   Foos foos;
};

int main() {
   std::cout << typeid(FooContainer<3>{}.foos).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 example.cc
$ ./a.out
St5tupleII3FooILm0EES0_ILm1EES0_ILm2EEEE
$ c++filt -t St5tupleII3FooILm0EES0_ILm1EES0_ILm2EEEE
std::tuple<Foo<0ul>, Foo<1ul>, Foo<2ul> >
```

**Edit:**

As skypjack mentioned one can now use our `FooContainer` class in an unexpected way by passing the second parameter explicitly... If passing arbitrary sequences in the second parameter of `FooContainer` is undesired one can guard the code by adding static_assert as follows:

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

template<size_t I> class Foo {};

template <size_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct FooContainer;

template <size_t N, size_t... Is>
struct FooContainer<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
   static_assert(std::is_same<std::make_index_sequence<N>, std::index_sequence<Is...>>::value, "passed index_sequence was not generated using std::make_index_sequence<N>");
   using Foos = std::tuple<Foo<Is>...>;
   Foos foos;
};

int main() {
   std::cout << typeid(FooContainer<3>{}.foos).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Good one. Chapeau. I'd add a parameter pack as a guard anyway, otherwise one can work around the second parameter.

Comment: @skypjack True, but one can treat it as a feature e.g. if he/she wants different permutation of 0..N one can simply pass appropriate `std::index_sequence` to it... :)

Comment: @skypjack if not `static_assert(std::is_same<std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::make_index_sequence<N>>::value, "not a monotonic sequence!");` can do the trick :)