# Incomplete type on gcc x86 but not on ARM

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, arm

The following program:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<uint32_t id>
class Foo {};

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041236/tuple-of-sequence
template<uint32_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>> class FooManagerImpl;

template<uint32_t N, uint32_t... ids>
class FooManagerImpl<N, std::index_sequence<ids...>>
{
    std::tuple<Foo<ids>...> foos;
};

using FooManager = FooManagerImpl<7U>;

int main()
{
    FooManager mm;
    return 0;
}
```

compiles with the GCC toolchain on ARM:

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -Wall -Werror -std=c++14 -o main.o main.cpp
```

but it fails when I try to compile it on x86:

```
g++ -c -Wall -Werror -std=c++14 -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:21:16: error: aggregate ‘FooManager mm’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
     FooManager mm;
                ^
Makefile:25: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I guess there must be a bug in one of the compilers, but I cannot tell whether the x86 is right to complain.

Also if someone knows how to fix this that would be great.

Compiler versions are both gcc 5.4:

```
$ /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --version
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1) 5.4.0 20160609
```

and

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
```