# Making an index sequence tuple

Tags: c++

Is there a way to create index tuple with compile-time known size like

```cpp
std::tuple<int, int, ...> tup = make_index_tuple(100); // -> tup == (0, 1, 2, ..., 99)
```

Maybe somehow using `std::make_index_sequence`? 
There is a kind of similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041236/tuple-of-sequence) about uninitialized tuple type but with structures involved

**EDIT**
I am  trying to test my hand-written string formatting function with a signature like this

```cpp
template<class... Args>
std::string format(std::string_view fmt, const Args&... args)
```

so I implemented a test, that requires to pass a sequence of ints 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 99 to args. If there is a way to create tuple like so, then I could use `std::apply` to pass required arguments. If there are other ways i'd be glad to hear them too :)

Comment: This just sounds like `std::array`. Is there a reason you're not using that type?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo i need to pass that tuple to variadic template, so array doesn't help. But! There is implementation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) how to make tuple from array. Maybe there is hope

Comment: I smell an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you elaborate on "need to pass that tuple to variadic template"?

Comment: `std::integer_sequence` is all about template parmeter packs, while you ask to get a value. Thats different story. Also the question you link is about getting a type not an object

Comment: i suspect you misunderstood something. Some background would help to clarify

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 i've corrected the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> pass a sequence of ints 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 99 to [function arguments]

You don't need tuples. Do this:

```
template <std::size_t ...I>
void foo(std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    format("foo", I...);
}

int main()
{
    foo(std::make_index_sequence<42>());
}
```

---

If you insist on `std::apply`, it understands `std::array` out of the box. You just need to handle the first parameter separately, since it's not an `int`.

```
const int n = 32;
std::array<int, n> array;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    array[i] = i;
std::apply([](auto ...params){format("foo", params...);}, array);
```

---

For educational purposes, here's the answer to the original question. This is how you make a tuple:

```
template <typename T, typename I>
struct n_tuple_helper {};

template <typename T, std::size_t ...I>
struct n_tuple_helper<T, std::index_sequence<I...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<std::enable_if_t<I || true, T>...>;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using n_tuple = typename n_tuple_helper<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>::type;
```

Now, `n_tuple<int, 3>` expands to `std::tuple<int, int, int>`

Comment: Excuse me, could you explain why you use (I || true ) instead of true ?

Comment: @Ben_LCDB Because 0 == false.

Comment: @Ben_LCDB It has to contain the pack name (`I`), otherwise `...` isn't going to work (because it wouldn't know how many times to repeat the thing).

Answer (score 1):

Above have mentioned how you could accomplish your idea by creating `std::array`. In case you still want to see how you should create a `tuple`:

```
template<typename T, T ...I>
auto make_tuple_sequence_helper(std::integer_sequence<T, I...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(I...);
}


template<std::size_t I, typename T>
auto make_tuple_sequence()
{
    return make_tuple_sequence_helper(std::make_integer_sequence<T, I>());
}
```

Then you call it in main:

```
auto int_tuple = make_tuple_sequence<5, int>();
// Equivalent to `std::make_tuple(0,1,2,3,4)`

auto long_tuple = make_tuple_sequence<5, long>();
// Equivalent to `std::make_tuple(0l,1l,2l,3l,4l)`

auto size_t_tuple = make_tuple_sequence<5, std::size_t>();
// Equivalent to `std::make_tuple(0z,1z,2z,3z,4z)`
```

---

Note that you could also remove the `typename T`, if you know you only want `tuple<int...>` :

```
template<int ...I>
auto make_tuple_sequence_helper(std::integer_sequence<int, I...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(I...);
}


template<std::size_t I,>
auto make_tuple_sequence()
{
    return make_tuple_sequence_helper(std::make_integer_sequence<int, I>());
}
```

And in main would be:

```
auto int_tuple = make_tuple_sequence<5>();
```